# How to enable cloud watch alarm / event rule for AWS spot interruption notification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi came to know that I can enable `AWS cloud watch alarm` for `AWS EC2 spot intance` if there is intrputtion for termination notice, [here is more details](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-ec2-spot-two-minute-warning-is-now-available-via-amazon-cloudwatch-events/)

> Now CloudWatch users can setup a [rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-rule.html) that automatically sends the EC2
>   Spot two-minute warning to an SNS topic to get a push notification.

I have no clue how to setup SNS topic to get intrputtion for termination notice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an SNS [topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-create-topic.html#create-topic-aws-console) and subscribe to this topic to get notifications.
2. Create a CloudWatch [Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CWE_GettingStarted.html) to trigger an action whenever a spot instance is terminated. 
   Configure your event as shown in the screenshot below.
3. Select *SNS Topic* as the target and enter the ARN of the topic you created.

[image]